# Unity ignores part of the code in the condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player movement code like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private float speed = 4f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1f;
    private float gravity = 9.81f;
    Vector3 lastMovementVector = Vector3.zero;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(velocity.y + " | " + controller.isGrounded); // Test

        Walk();
        Jump();
    }

    private void Walk()
    {
        Vector3 movementVector = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            // This part executes
            controller.Move(movementVector * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            lastMovementVector = movementVector * Time.deltaTime * speed / 2f;
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Move(lastMovementVector); // Сontinues in flight
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            // I already checked with bool, this part doesn't execute
            if (velocity.y < 0)
            {
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * 2f * gravity);
            }
        }
        velocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

**I check if the player is on the ground - he is.**

**But this part is ignored and not executed:**

```
if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            // I already checked with bool, this part doesn't execute
            if (velocity.y < 0)
            {
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * 2f * gravity);
            }
        }
```

I can't jump until I move. But when I start to move it starts to сheck!

Although both parts of the code have the same condition.

I'm shocked that he just ignores this part of the code. I've been sitting for half an hour already.

Comment: Debug debug. Is controller.IsGrounded still true there when Jump is called? How about if you comment out the Walk call and try to only Jump, does it still get ignored?

Comment: @Saplu No, controller.isGrounded becomes false. And when I comment out the Walk() -  Jump dont get ignored! What it means?

Comment: I dont know, but I guess that something happens when you call controller.Move inside walk. That could affect controller.Grounded also.

Comment: You could try to move the grounded check out of walk and jump methods and only check it in the beginning of each update. Then add it as parameter to both methods so that changes made in first call dont affect the execution of second. Or make it a private field and change its value in the update, then you dont need to add parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it works but I solved it by simply adding a variable `isGrounded`...

This is how the code looks like now :

```
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private float speed = 4f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1f;
    private float gravity = 9.81f;
    Vector3 lastMovementVector = Vector3.zero;
    private bool isGrounded; // This is new variable

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(velocity.y + " | " + controller.isGrounded);

        isGrounded = controller.isGrounded; // Equated to property

        Walk();
        Jump();
    }

    private void Walk()
    {
        Vector3 movementVector = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            controller.Move(movementVector * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            lastMovementVector = movementVector * Time.deltaTime * speed / 2f;
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Move(lastMovementVector);
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (velocity.y < 0)
            {
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * 2f * gravity);
            }
        }
        velocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```